# How do I change the volume of an iframe element?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On my site, I have an iframe element that is playing music (I cannot use a audio element in this instance) and I would like to be able to change the volume using a slider.

I have tried the following:

HTML:

```
<iframe src="bg.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio"></iframe>
<input id="vol-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)" />
```

Javascript:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeAudio');
iframe.setVolume(val / 100);
```

However, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: iframe.setVolume is not a function
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This feature is unfortunately not supported in most browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/setVolume You might be better off using the HTML5 audio tag or webaudio rather than an iframe to play the sound.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in a different way with a small trick like this:

you can upload the video you want to your YouTube channel then

1. head over the video you want on the YouTube to grab the video ID, you will find it after `v=` like this

[image]

So in our example here the video ID is `_cB8CE_Q3Yk`

2. To control the volume or any other property

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube API</title>
    <!--to load YouTube "iframe_api" asynchronously-->
    <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_YouTube"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

        var player;

        player = new YT.Player('div_YouTube', {
            videoId: '_cB8CE_Q3Yk',   //  video id.
            width: 560,
            height: 316,
            playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 1,
                'controls': 1,
                'showinfo': 0,
                'modestbranding': 0,
                'loop': 1,
                'fs': 0,
                'cc_load_policty': 0,
                'iv_load_policy': 3
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': function (e) {
                  e.target.setVolume(100); // For max value, set value to 100.
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

And for more info about IFrame Player API:

1. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
2. https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/youtube-api-embed-video-with-mute-sound-setvolume-onstatechange-event.htm

Comment: Hey @Mohamed S.Shelf, the OP has not asked about the youtube player, please improve your answer.

Comment: Hey @HarshSaini ,  I know that well, so that I said "You can do this in a different way" - because he would upload the video he wants to add as a source to the iframe to YouTube and then embed it again as I mention in my answer.